# How to set color to a Smarty variable?

Tags: php, frontend, html, design, frontend-model

I got a piece of code as seen in the image below in a Smarty template outputting the payment method. Please help me a find a way to set color "red" only to the value of `"{$search_results_list[searchresults].cc_type}"`. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does the surrounding HTML look like?

If you cannot edit the HTML to add classes you could use :nth selector to select that second span tag, ie.

```
.surrounding-div span:nth-child(2) {color: red;}
```

Or if there are multiple span elements you could get more specific like this:

```
.surrounding-div span[title^="Payment"]:nth-of-type(2) {color: red;}
```

If you provide more of the template HTML it would be easier to answer more accurately.

Comment: Thanks Readio. Your solution looks more elegant and useful when having multiple span elements.